# How to send Parameter in ElFileBody for GraphQL StringBody in Gatling

Tags: scala, graphql, gatling

I am trying to send the parameter {NEW_ID} to GraphQL using ElFileBody. The contents of GraphQL are stored in a simple plain text file in Gatling `/resources/data` folder. I keep getting a 500 error, and I think I am very close in getting the implementation right but I'm not sure what mistake I am making. Can someone guide me?

Here is GraphQL contents which is stored in registerPlayer.txt file under `/resources/data` folder:

```
        {
          "query": "mutation registerPlayerByEmail(\n  $eventId: ID!,\n  $emailAddress: String!) {\n  registerPlayerByEmail(eventId: $eventId, emailAddress: $emailAddress) {\n    ...EventFields\n    ...PlayerListFields\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment EventFields on Event {\n  id\n  status\n  title\n  format\n  limitedSet\n  rulesEnforcementLevel\n  entryFee {\n    amount\n currency\n    __typename\n  }\n  venue {\n    id\n    name\n    latitude\n    longitude\n    address\n    timeZone\n    phoneNumber\n    emailAddress\n    __typename\n  }\n  capacity\n  description\n  scheduledStartTime\n  estimatedEndTime\n  latitude\n  longitude\n  address\n  timeZone\n  phoneNumber\n  emailAddress\n  shortCode\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment PlayerListFields on Event {\n  registeredPlayers {\n    id\n    personaId\n    displayName\n    emailAddress\n    firstName\n    lastName\n    status\n    __typename\n  }\n  interestedPlayers {\n    personaId\n    displayName\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}",
          "variables": {
            "eventId":${NEW_ID},
            "emailAddress":"automation-player1@abc.com"
          }
        }
```

Here is the code.

```
            class gamekeeper extends BaseSimulation {


              val uri2 = "https://api.platform.abc.com"


              val headers_0 = Map(
                "accept" -> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
              )



              val headers_10 = Map(
                "accept" -> "application/json, text/plain, */*",
              )




              val headers_3 = Map(
                "Content-Type" -> "application/json",


              )




              val headers_startEvent = Map(
                "Content-Type" -> "application/json",
                "Authorization" -> "Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}"

              )

              val headers_startNextRound = Map(
                "Content-Type" -> "application/json",
                "Authorization" -> "Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}"

              )

              val headers_submitResults = Map(
                "Content-Type" -> "application/json",
                "Authorization" -> "Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}"

              )

              val headers_certifyResults = Map(
                "Content-Type" -> "application/json",
                "Authorization" -> "Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}"

              )

              val headers_endEvent = Map(
                "Content-Type" -> "application/json",
                "Authorization" -> "Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}"

              )





              val headers_36 = Map(
                "authorization" -> "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjM0NmM4YTY1NTBlZGI5MDRjM2IyNWI3ODlmOTllNjU3ODA4MGJiOTUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJXSlJZREhOR1JPSVpITDhCIiwiZXhwIjoxNTgwMjgxMTc1LCJpYXQiOjE1ODAyODAyMTUsImlzcyI6IjRDVTZUQlBDUlpHUk5FV0ZETkE2Q0ZEUDU0Iiwic3ViIjoiTFpPSVBCSzZTNURJVkQyWVJDR0dDT0JGRzQiLCJ3b3RjLW5hbWUiOiJhdXRvbWF0aW9uU3RvcmVBZG1pbjEjODg1NzQiLCJ3b3RjLWRvbW4iOiJ3aXphcmRzIiwid290Yy1nYW1lIjoiZXZlbnRyZXBvcnRlciIsIndvdGMtZmxncyI6OSwid290Yy1yb2xzIjpbXSwid290Yy1wcm1zIjpbXSwid290Yy1zY3BzIjpbImZpcnN0LXBhcnR5Il0sIndvdGMtcGRnciI6IiIsIndvdGMtc2d0cyI6W10sIndvdGMtc29jbCI6e319.Uou737of2lHQTZafsiHDfe0qxgi1lMvnAKEKpSa9Lhm5VSaFtX0ajwlLmj49hA5VuyrCGg-TjhgxTvk_8Kt_LdxTnlntb19tlvUVtlQsNcDsbnP4Ts5XCsyu8fR-TwRx85502-j0qP5ivDg5cP0QKVYroJg8vUSBOu_3eMGaiVTPpdRweJuRQc-rMFAPXwWyhKXNzRV-NfvlL7cEfCiRBLwap5PQ9i0UmbLTk1u6_t-oVgegRf5vjwii7_5icW1J1iemRCVvT5dQzy1qyLavBPXKH9Lee8h0TKswubVoKkWSUnvxavP6EtkSx8Q_5kWvmT3Nba4txhjCuqvIO9HKSw",
                "cache-control" -> "no-cache",
                "content-type" -> "application/json",
                "origin" -> "https://retailer-dev.abc.com",
                "pragma" -> "no-cache",
                "referer" -> "https://retailer-dev.abc.com/stores/26015/events/825926/pairings",
                "sec-fetch-mode" -> "cors",
                "sec-fetch-site" -> "same-site")

              val headers_PrivateEvent = Map(
                "Content-Type" -> "application/json",
                "Authorization" -> "Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}"

                )



              val RegisterPlayer = Map("Content-Type" -> "application/json","Authorization" -> "Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" )

              val usersDataSource=jsonFile("C:/Gatling2/gatling3james/src/gatling/resources/data/input-gamekeeper.json").circular
              val nameDataSource=jsonFile("C:/Gatling2/gatling3james/src/gatling/resources/data/input-gamekeeper-StringBody.json").random









              val source: String = Source.fromFile("C:/Gatling2/gatling3james/src/gatling/resources/data/input-gamekeeper.json").getLines.mkString
              def userCount: Int  = JsonPath.parse(source).read("$.[0].user")
              def testDuration: Int  = JsonPath.parse(source).read("$.[0].testDuration")
              def rampDuration: Int  = JsonPath.parse(source).read("$.[0].rampDuration")



              before {
                println(s"Running test with ${userCount} users")
                println(s"Ramping users over ${rampDuration} seconds")
                println(s"Total Test duration: ${testDuration} seconds")
              }






              val createPrivateEvent ={





                    exec(http("Create Private Event")


                      .post("https://api.tabletop-stage.abc-origin.cloud/dev/silverbeak-griffin-service/graphql")
                      .headers(headers_PrivateEvent)
                      .body(ElFileBody("createeventasWER.txt"))

                      .check(status.in(200,201))
                      .check(bodyString.saveAs("PrivateEvent_Response"))

                      .check(jsonPath(path="$.data.createEvent.id").saveAs(key="EventId")))


                      .exec { session => session.set("NEW_ID", session("EventId").as[String]) }
                      .exec{session=>println(session);session}
                    .pause(1)

                  }



              object  RegPlayer {

                val RegisterPlayer1 = {


                  exec(http("Register Player 1")


                    .post("https://api.tabletop-stage.abc-origin.cloud/dev/silverbeak-griffin-service/graphql")
                    .headers(RegisterPlayer)
                    .body(ElFileBody("registerPlayer.txt"))

                    .check(status.in(200, 201))
                    .check(bodyString.saveAs("Player1_Response")))

                    .exec { session => println(session); session }
                    .pause(1)


                }







              }

            object gamekeeper{



              val startEvent = {


                exec(http("Start Event")


                  .post("https://api.tabletop-stage.abc-origin.cloud/dev/silverbeak-griffin-service/" + "graphql" )

                  .headers(headers_startEvent)

                  .body(ElFileBody("startEvent.txt"))

                  .check(status.in(200, 201))
                  .check(bodyString.saveAs("StartEvent_Response")))




                  .exec { session => println(session); session }
                  .pause(1)


              }


              val startNextRound = {


                exec(http("Start Next Round")


                  .post("https://api.tabletop-stage.abc-origin.cloud/dev/silverbeak-griffin-service/" + "graphql" )
                  .headers(headers_startNextRound)

                  .body(ElFileBody("createNextRound.txt"))

                  .check(status.in(200, 201))
                  .check(jsonPath(path="$.data.createNextRound.currentRound.matches[0].id").saveAs(key="currentMatchId"))
                  .check(jsonPath(path="$.data.createNextRound.currentRound.matches[0].teams[1].id").saveAs(key="rightTeamId"))
                  .check(jsonPath(path="$.data.createNextRound.currentRound.matches[0].teams[0].id").saveAs(key="leftTeamId"))
                  .check(jsonPath(path="$.data.createNextRound.currentRound.matches[1].isBye").saveAs(key="isBye"))
                  .check(jsonPath(path="$.data.createNextRound.currentRound.matches[1].leftTeamWins").saveAs(key="leftTeamWins"))
                  .check(jsonPath(path="$.data.createNextRound.currentRound.matches[1].rightTeamWins").saveAs(key="rightTeamWins"))
                  .check(bodyString.saveAs("createNextRound")))



                  .exec { session => session.set("currentMatchId", session("currentMatchId").as[String]).set("leftTeamId", session("leftTeamId").as[String]).set("rightTeamId", session("rightTeamId").as[String]).set("isBye", session("isBye").as[String]).set("leftTeamWins", session("leftTeamWins").as[String]).set("rightTeamWins", session("rightTeamWins").as[String])set("matchResults", matchResults) }
                  .exec{session=>println(session);session}
                  .pause(1)


              }

              val submitResults = {


                exec(http("Submit Results")


                  .post("https://api.tabletop-stage.abc-origin.cloud/dev/silverbeak-griffin-service/" + "graphql" )
                  .headers(headers_submitResults)




                  .body(ElFileBody("submitResults.txt"))


                  .check(status.in(200, 201))
                  .check(bodyString.saveAs("submitResults_Response")))




                  .exec { session => println(session); session }
                  .pause(1)


              }


            }



              val login = exec( exec(http("PlatForm Auth Url")

                  .post(uri2 + "/auth/oauth/token")
                  .headers(headers_10)
                  .formParam("grant_type", "password")
                  .formParam("username", "store-admin1@abc.com")
                  .formParam("password", "fJC2RuVdvmHB")
                  .basicAuth("WJRYDHNGROIZHL8B","V5VXK6FLG1YI0GD2XY3H")
                  .check(bodyString.saveAs("Login_Response"))
                  .check(jsonPath("$.access_token").exists.saveAs("access_token"))
                  .check(jsonPath("$.token_type").exists.saveAs("token_type")))
                .exec{session=>println(session);session}

                .exec { session => session.set("ACCESS_TOKEN", session("access_token").as[String]).set("TOKEN_TYPE", session("token_type").as[String]) }


              )







              val scenario4 = scenario("Full GameKeeper ").exec(login).exec(createPrivateEvent).exec(RegPlayer.RegisterPlayer1)







              setUp(


                scenario4.inject(
                  nothingFor(5 seconds),
                  rampUsers(userCount) over ( rampDuration ))
                  .protocols(httpProtocol)


              )


                .maxDuration(testDuration)
            }
```

Here is the console log:-

```
                 "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.5\lib\idea_rt.jar=10303:C:\Program  

            Running test with 1 users
            Ramping users over 2 seconds
            Total Test duration: 180 seconds
            Simulation simulations.gamekeeper started...

            ================================================================================
            2020-01-30 17:16:16                                           5s elapsed
            ---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
            > Global                                                   (OK=0      KO=0     )


            ---- Full GameKeeper  ----------------------------------------------------------
            [                                                                          ]  0%
                      waiting: 1      / active: 0      / done:0     
            ================================================================================

            Session(Full GameKeeper ,1,Map(access_token -> w5EBdxPbUJ74HKrV0d8CwnF_Wzmo_DaB9GF3tuz1hmyKuVMFymip8fvMByOG48WWE-OEuMtNmQjaGDp3rTvVjIqJeUS4sS2-VOB8iGiDqQFQaCXUiHUOcvsXxb3Y9ctwqK3MCOqikAeKmc_lymjtJ4Y0MDJ94AV11p1TiDnD8V7yQUnz3lD4-FvQEWnhcOU2TOkrRdnpAdCKqnXYcI2nvzX3g-N-P2MS8rgwnijZhhVMXYkkPcqHg, token_type -> Bearer, EventId -> 834153, NEW_ID -> 834153, Login_Response -> {"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjM0NmM4YTY1NTBlZGI5MDRjM2IyNWI3ODlmOTllNjU3ODA4MGJiOTUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJXSlJZREhOR1JPSVpITDhCIiwiZXhwIjoxNTgwNDM0MzM3LCJpYXQiOjE1ODA0MzMzNzcsImlzcyI6IkhJSlpYWjVSWFpCNzNNT0lFRVBJVVNJUVk0Iiwic3ViIjoiQ0M3R0lIVEdOVkVMTkJINU1OSllHSlFLS0kiLCJ3b3RjLW5hbWUiOiJTcG9jayM4MTEzMiIsIndvdGMtZG9tbiI6IndpemFyZHMiLCJ3b3RjLWdhbWUiOiJldmVudHJlcG9ydGVyIiwid290Yy1mbGdzIjoxLCJ3b3RjLXJvbHMiOltdLCJ3b3RjLXBybXMiOltdLCJ3b3RjLXNjcHMiOlsiZmlyc3QtcGFydHkiXSwid290Yy1wZGdyIjoiS1E1TVI3V09ENUZSSENBTVVaWlBEVEpFVlkiLCJ3b3RjLXNndHMiOltdLCJ3b3RjLXNvY2wiOnt9fQ.mOvL_543_AkUmDECC7PQ_T_DkZFQlJ9Hqm249W64hfEah0UjELUiUzEjo5hQNfzcPVKccS0RUPglitsi16Ss2qzWcCuJN8ME-w5EBdxPbUJ74HKrV0d8CwnF_Wzmo_DaB9GF3tuz1hmyKuVMFymip8fvMByOG48WWE-OEuMtNmQjaGDp3rTvVjIqJeUS4sS2-VOB8iGiDqQFQaCXUiHUOcvsXxb3Y9ctwqK3MCOqikAeKmc_lymjtJ4Y0MDJ94AV11p1TiDnD8V7yQUnz3lD4-FvQEWnhcOU2TOkrRdnpAdCKqnXYcI2nvzX3g-N-P2MS8rgwnijZhhVMXYkkPcqHg","refresh_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjM0NmM4YTY1NTBlZGI5MDRjM2IyNWI3ODlmOTllNjU3ODA4MGJiOTUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJXSlJZREhOR1JPSVpITDhCIiwiZXhwIjoxNTgxNjQyOTc3LCJpYXQiOjE1ODA0MzMzNzcsImlzcyI6IkhJSlpYWjVSWFpCNzNNT0lFRVBJVVNJUVk0Iiwic3ViIjoiQ0M3R0lIVEdOVkVMTkJINU1OSllHSlFLS0kiLCJ3b3RjLWRvbW4iOiJ3aXphcmRzIiwid290Yy1zY3BzIjpbImZpcnN0LXBhcnR5Il0sIndvdGMtZmxncyI6MSwid290Yy1wZGdyIjoiS1E1TVI3V09ENUZSSENBTVVaWlBEVEpFVlkiLCJ3b3RjLXNvY2wiOnt9fQ.Wp-5PVn3xGhQ1slpBttUI2qXd7iHUWfu3SB-6kYKj3FHZLnDPFdsdZ7TOsd8mctLvZb9lh6Moaf0FNSGF5ru3OFpA7OFvXiMKjHIhKk3gV6EFYkVvj_P4rL2X3CyRMcIVmEIoyGAQHdW-9G3_5jEGBdWN3AxYbQs0k66NpXT567nikOSbp0AlaCDvjy0jAORjYOs2-R6rsvS-dc9u1LGWbTdC6euo5mrmwbWRRxDQb2eaYBYoYclRZ1Xm50vWiIGsmD0YJFwBt6vdSuWMx2ePK2ZfbN5499zthjibOLtF0XQJb_P4a2qr5p9E0BDbRDQlNG4AmKDDnVZa_v4JTrmhw","expires_in":900,"token_type":"Bearer","client_id":"WJRYDHNGROIZHL8B","game_id":"eventreporter","domain_id":"abc","persona_id":"CC7GIHTGNVELNBH5MNJYGJQKKI","account_id":"HIJZXZ5RXZB73MOIEEPIUSIQY4","display_name":"Spock#81132"}, TOKEN_TYPE -> Bearer, PrivateEvent_Response -> {"data":{"createEvent":{"id":"834153","status":"SCHEDULED","title":"TestUpdatedServicesEvent","format":"WOTC_DRAFT","limitedSet":"CORE_SET_2020","rulesEnforcementLevel":"CASUAL","pairingType":"SWISS","entryFee":{"amount":500,"currency":"USD","__typename":"Money"},"venue":null,"capacity":8,"description":"test","scheduledStartTime":"2020-01-22T12:00:00Z","estimatedEndTime":"2020-01-22T16:00:00Z","latitude":47.66499,"longitude":-122.38043,"address":null,"timeZone":"America/Los_Angeles","phoneNumber":"206-523-9605","emailAddress":"test@gameogretest.com","shortCode":"55NZJW","__typename":"Event"}}}
            ),1580433377365,150,OK,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$453/1618326227@748d67fb)
            Session(Full GameKeeper ,1,Map(access_token -> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjM0NmM4YTY1NTBlZGI5MDRjM2IyNWI3ODlmOTllNjU3ODA4MGJiOTUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJXSlJZREhOR1JPSVpITDhCIiwiZXhwIjoxNTgwNDM0MzM3LCJpYXQiOjE1ODA0MzMzNzcsImlzcyI6IkhJSlpYWjVSWFpCNzNNT0lFRVBJVVNJUVk0Iiwic3ViIjoiQ0M3R0lIVEdOVkVMTkJINU1OSllHSlFLS0kiLCJ3b3RjLW5hbWUiOiJTcG9jayM4MTEzMiIsIndvdGMtZG9tbiI6IndpemFyZHMiLCJ3b3RjLWdhbWUiOiJldmVudHJlcG9ydGVyIiwid290Yy1mbGdzIjoxLCJ3b3RjLXJvbHMiOltdLCJ3b3RjLXBybXMiOltdLCJ3b3RjLXNjcHMiOlsiZmlyc3QtcGFydHkiXSwid290Yy1wZGdyIjoiS1E1TVI3V09ENUZSSENBTVVaWlBEVEpFVlkiLCJ3b3RjLXNndHMiOltdLCJ3b3RjLXNvY2wiOnt9fQ.mOvL_543_AkUmDECC7PQ_T_DkZFQlJ9Hqm249W64hfEah0UjELUiUzEjo5hQNfzcPVKccS0RUPglitsi16Ss2qzWcCuJN8ME-w5EBdxPbUJ74HKrV0d8CwnF_Wzmo_DaB9GF3tuz1hmyKuVMFymip8fvMByOG48WWE-OEuMtNmQjaGDp3rTvVjIqJeUS4sS2-VOB8iGiDqQFQaCXUiHUOcvsXxb3Y9ctwqK3MCOqikAeKmc_lymjtJ4Y0MDJ94AV11p1TiDnD8V7yQUnz3lD4-FvQEWnhcOU2TOkrRdnpAdCKqnXYcI2nvzX3g-N-P2MS8rgwnijZhhVMXYkkPcqHg, gatling.http.cache.dns -> io.gatling.http.resolver.ShuffleJdkNameResolver@be2d2a0, gatling.http.cache.contentCache -> io.gatling.core.util.cache.Cache@2f40e1, ACCESS_TOKEN -> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjM0NmM4YTY1NTBlZGI5MDRjM2IyNWI3ODlmOTllNjU3ODA4MGJiOTUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJXSlJZREhOR1JPSVpITDhCIiwiZXhwIjoxNTgwNDM0MzM3LCJpYXQiOjE1ODA0MzMzNzcsImlzcyI6IkhJSlpYWjVSWFpCNzNNT0lFRVBJVVNJUVk0Iiwic3ViIjoiQ0M3R0lIVEdOVkVMTkJINU1OSllHSlFLS0kiLCJ3b3RjLW5hbWUiOiJTcG9jayM4MTEzMiIsIndvdGMtZG9tbiI6IndpemFyZHMiLCJ3b3RjLWdhbWUiOiJldmVudHJlcG9ydGVyIiwid290Yy1mbGdzIjoxLCJ3b3RjLXJvbHMiOltdLCJ3b3RjLXBybXMiOltdLCJ3b3RjLXNjcHMiOlsiZmlyc3QtcGFydHkiXSwid290Yy1wZGdyIjoiS1E1TVI3V09ENUZSSENBTVVaWlBEVEpFVlkiLCJ3b3RjLXNndHMiOltdLCJ3b3RjLXNvY2wiOnt9fQ.mOvL_543_AkUmDECC7PQ_T_DkZFQlJ9Hqm249W64hfEah0UjELUiUzEjo5hQNfzcPVKccS0RUPglitsi16Ss2qzWcCuJN8ME-w5EBdxPbUJ74HKrV0d8CwnF_Wzmo_DaB9GF3tuz1hmyKuVMFymip8fvMByOG48WWE-OEuMtNmQjaGDp3rTvVjIqJeUS4sS2-VOB8iGiDqQFQaCXUiHUOcvsXxb3Y9ctwqK3MCOqikAeKmc_lymjtJ4Y0MDJ94AV11p1TiDnD8V7yQUnz3lD4-FvQEWnhcOU2TOkrRdnpAdCKqnXYcI2nvzX3g-N-P2MS8rgwnijZhhVMXYkkPcqHg, token_type -> Bearer, EventId -> 834153, NEW_ID -> 834153, Login_Response -> {"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjM0NmM4YTY1NTBlZGI5MDRjM2IyNWI3ODlmOTllNjU3ODA4MGJiOTUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJXSlJZREhOR1JPSVpITDhCIiwiZXhwIjoxNTgwNDM0MzM3LCJpYXQiOjE1ODA0MzMzNzcsImlzcyI6IkhJSlpYWjVSWFpCNzNNT0lFRVBJVVNJUVk0Iiwic3ViIjoiQ0M3R0lIVEdOVkVMTkJINU1OSllHSlFLS0kiLCJ3b3RjLW5hbWUiOiJTcG9jayM4MTEzMiIsIndvdGMtZG9tbiI6IndpemFyZHMiLCJ3b3RjLWdhbWUiOiJldmVudHJlcG9ydGVyIiwid290Yy1mbGdzIjoxLCJ3b3RjLXJvbHMiOltdLCJ3b3RjLXBybXMiOltdLCJ3b3RjLXNjcHMiOlsiZmlyc3QtcGFydHkiXSwid290Yy1wZGdyIjoiS1E1TVI3V09ENUZSSENBTVVaWlBEVEpFVlkiLCJ3b3RjLXNndHMiOltdLCJ3b3RjLXNvY2wiOnt9fQ.mOvL_543_AkUmDECC7PQ_T_DkZFQlJ9Hqm249W64hfEah0UjELUiUzEjo5hQNfzcPVKccS0RUPglitsi16Ss2qzWcCuJN8ME-w5EBdxPbUJ74HKrV0d8CwnF_Wzmo_DaB9GF3tuz1hmyKuVMFymip8fvMByOG48WWE-OEuMtNmQjaGDp3rTvVjIqJeUS4sS2-VOB8iGiDqQFQaCXUiHUOcvsXxb3Y9ctwqK3MCOqikAeKmc_lymjtJ4Y0MDJ94AV11p1TiDnD8V7yQUnz3lD4-FvQEWnhcOU2TOkrRdnpAdCKqnXYcI2nvzX3g-N-P2MS8rgwnijZhhVMXYkkPcqHg","refresh_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjM0NmM4YTY1NTBlZGI5MDRjM2IyNWI3ODlmOTllNjU3ODA4MGJiOTUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJXSlJZREhOR1JPSVpITDhCIiwiZXhwIjoxNTgxNjQyOTc3LCJpYXQiOjE1ODA0MzMzNzcsImlzcyI6IkhJSlpYWjVSWFpCNzNNT0lFRVBJVVNJUVk0Iiwic3ViIjoiQ0M3R0lIVEdOVkVMTkJINU1OSllHSlFLS0kiLCJ3b3RjLWRvbW4iOiJ3aXphcmRzIiwid290Yy1zY3BzIjpbImZpcnN0LXBhcnR5Il0sIndvdGMtZmxncyI6MSwid290Yy1wZGdyIjoiS1E1TVI3V09ENUZSSENBTVVaWlBEVEpFVlkiLCJ3b3RjLXNvY2wiOnt9fQ.Wp-5PVn3xGhQ1slpBttUI2qXd7iHUWfu3SB-6kYKj3FHZLnDPFdsdZ7TOsd8mctLvZb9lh6Moaf0FNSGF5ru3OFpA7OFvXiMKjHIhKk3gV6EFYkVvj_P4rL2X3CyRMcIVmEIoyGAQHdW-9G3_5jEGBdWN3AxYbQs0k66NpXT567nikOSbp0AlaCDvjy0jAORjYOs2-R6rsvS-dc9u1LGWbTdC6euo5mrmwbWRRxDQb2eaYBYoYclRZ1Xm50vWiIGsmD0YJFwBt6vdSuWMx2ePK2ZfbN5499zthjibOLtF0XQJb_P4a2qr5p9E0BDbRDQlNG4AmKDDnVZa_v4JTrmhw","expires_in":900,"token_type":"Bearer","client_id":"WJRYDHNGROIZHL8B","game_id":"eventreporter","domain_id":"abc","persona_id":"CC7GIHTGNVELNBH5MNJYGJQKKI","account_id":"HIJZXZ5RXZB73MOIEEPIUSIQY4","display_name":"Spock#81132"}, Player1_Response -> {"errors":[{"message":"500: Internal Server Error","locations":[{"line":4,"column":3}],"path":["registerPlayerByEmail"],"extensions":{"code":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","response":{"url":"http://event-reservations-service-dev.event-reservation-service.svc.cluster.local/events/834153/registrations","status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error","body":""},"exception":{"stacktrace":["Error: 500: Internal Server Error","    at EventReservationsService.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/apollo-datasource-rest/dist/RESTDataSource.js:84:25)","    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)","    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/apollo-datasource-rest/dist/RESTDataSource.js:8:71","    at new Promise (<anonymous>)","    at __awaiter (/usr/src/app/node_modules/apollo-datasource-rest/dist/RESTDataSource.js:4:12)","    at EventReservationsService.errorFromResponse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/apollo-datasource-rest/dist/RESTDataSource.js:74:16)","    at EventReservationsService.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/apollo-datasource-rest/dist/RESTDataSource.js:52:34)","    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)","    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/apollo-datasource-rest/dist/RESTDataSource.js:8:71","    at new Promise (<anonymous>)"]}}}],"data":{"registerPlayerByEmail":null}}
            , TOKEN_TYPE -> Bearer, PrivateEvent_Response -> {"data":{"createEvent":{"id":"834153","status":"SCHEDULED","title":"TestUpdatedServicesEvent","format":"WOTC_DRAFT","limitedSet":"CORE_SET_2020","rulesEnforcementLevel":"CASUAL","pairingType":"SWISS","entryFee":{"amount":500,"currency":"USD","__typename":"Money"},"venue":null,"capacity":8,"description":"test","scheduledStartTime":"2020-01-22T12:00:00Z","estimatedEndTime":"2020-01-22T16:00:00Z","latitude":47.66499,"longitude":-122.38043,"address":null,"timeZone":"America/Los_Angeles","phoneNumber":"206-523-9605","emailAddress":"test@gameogretest.com","shortCode":"55NZJW","__typename":"Event"}}}
            ),1580433377365,25,OK,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$453/1618326227@748d67fb)


            Reports generated in 1s.
            Please open the following file: C:\Gatling2\gatling3james\results\gamekeeper-1580433371337\index.html

            Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. The irony is that the method `RegisterPlayer1` shows OK in Gatling but actually it is not because the Response body shows the detailed error response.

Comment: [Turn on logging](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/debugging#logback) to see actual requests sent and responses received.